# Cannot upgrade restify to latest 5.x

Tags: node.js, npm, restify

I am currently using restify version 4.0.3

I run this command;
`$ ncu -u`

I can see other npm packages being upgraded but not restify. I would like to upgrade restify to the latest 5.x. How can this be done? Any compatibility problems when upgrading from v4 to v5?

In my `package.json`,

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "restify": "^4.0.3",
    "restify-ensure-login": "^2.0.0",
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run "npm update restify"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your package.json to

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "restify": ">=4.0.3",
    "restify-ensure-login": "^2.0.0",
}
```